# IBOutlet or event for UIPageControl not in the StoryBoard

Tags: ios, swift, events, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I'm starting to program for Ios with Swift.

Although I have a doubt,

How can I do an IBOutlet or an event to control when I touch the right or left of the UIPageControl?

It's not in the StoryBoard, it's a variable.

I attach image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7Dv1.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't use an image to share the codes.

Comment: IBOutlet is access an element placed in a storyBoard via code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event for value Changed on the page control and handle the action.

self.pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pageControlValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)

@objc func pageControlValueChanged(sender: UIPageControl) {

}